# Pegar retorno em PHP JSON

Tags: php, json

Tem um sistema que enviara um retorno para mim todos os dias, porem não estou consegindo receber os dados para gravar no banco, alguem pode me dar uma luz?

Este são os dados enviados pelo sistema

```
 -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
    "uuid": "6ae29dfb29ad4dd29ce6bf454800c7db",
    "payment_type": "boleto",   
    "amount": 100,
    "status": "pending",   
    "external_id": "order 1",
    "expiration_date": "2018-07-13T21:00:00-03:00",
    "created_at": "2018-07-11T16:51:18-03:00"
}'
```

Preciso pegar uuid, expiration_date e status para gravar no banco!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tente usar a função [json_decode();](https://php.net/json-decode)

```
<?php
$json = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$uuid = $json['uuid'];
$payment_type = $json['payment_type'];
$amount = $json['amount'];
$status = $json['status'];
$external_id = $json['external_id'];
$expiration_date = $json['expiration_date'];
$created_at = $json['created_at'];
...
?>
```

Agora, só implementar o banco de dados.